# What are not non-negligible functions?

Tags: negligible

I had a brief look at ["On Defining Proofs of Knowledge" by Bellare and Goldreich](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/PS/pok.ps) and I am a little confused by their definitions.

I was under the impression a negligible function $f$ was defined as something like
$$\forall\ polynomials\ p\ \exists k\ s.t.\ \forall x > k: f(x) < \frac{1}{p(x)}$$

And that non-negligible meant simply that it was not negligible.
The paper however states:
"Put in other words negligible is not the negation of non-negligible!" (p. 5)
And this seems to be based on the definition "a non-negligible function in $n$ is a function which is asymptotically bounded from below by a function of the form $n^{-c}$ for some constant $c$" (p. 4) which I am losely translating as
$$\exists\ polynomial\ p\ and\ k\ s.t.\ \forall x > k: f(x) > \frac{1}{p(x)}$$
With the difference being functions which are somehow alternating.

This is a bit of a weird question because the mathematics seem to be clear but I am confused by what the common usage is.
And is this something that is generally important? I've never seen it discussed elsewhere.

Comment: What they seem to be calling "non-negligible" (I can't check the ps file on mobile) is usually called "noticable" and the standard caution is that "non-negligible" (in the sense you used it) is not equivalent to "noticable".

Comment: [See e.g. these lecture notes](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sanjamg/classes/cs276-fall14/scribe/lec02.pdf)

Comment: Or [page 9 of these](https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~lindell/89-856/main-89-856.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Negligible Function:** A function $\mu$ is *negligible* iff $\forall c \in N \;\; \exists n_0 \in N$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0, \mu(n) < n^{−c}.$

  As we generally know, a negligible function is smaller than any polynomial. We have also an equivalent limit definition;

  $f(n)$ is *negligible* than for every polynomial $q(n)$ we have;

  $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} q(n) f(n) =0$$

  The easy examples are the $2^{-n},2^{-\sqrt{n}}, \text{ and } n^{- \log n}$.
- **Non-Negligible Function:<sup>*</sup>** a function $\mu(n)$ is *non-negligible* iff
  $\exists c \in N$ such that $\forall n_0 \in N, \exists n \geq n_0$ such that $\mu(n) \geq n^{-c}.$

  To be non-negligible, only one candidate is enough to show that $n \geq n_0$ for which $\mu(n) \geq n^{-c}$.
- **Noticeable Function:** A function $\mu$ is *noticeable* iff $\exists c \in N, n_0 \in N$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0, \mu(n) \geq n^{-c}.$

  As we can see, the difference from non-negligibility is; *for all* $n \geq n_0$

  An example is $n^{-3}$ which is only polynomially slow ( like any polynomial)

  Weak One-Way Functions are defined on noticeable functions.

Interleaving is the key to generating distinguishing examples. Take any noticeable and negligible function and interleave them;

$$\mu(n) = \cases{ 2^{-n} & : $x$  is even \\ n^{-3} & : $x$  is odd}$$

$\mu$ is a non-negligible and non-noticeable function!.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>[Quantifiers negation](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Eandrewr/PLP.text/section-21.html): In the negation $\neg\forall = \exists$ and $\neg \exists = \forall$</sub>

Comment: Based on the comments, I've given a shot that our site has this written around...

Comment: This answer does not address the fact that the cited paper defines non-negligible differently.

Comment: @Maeher I'm aware of this. These definitions are the same as in Oded Goldreich's Foundations of Cryptography Volume I. So, I can say this is common usage as OP asked. If we consider the date of the article as '92 and the book as  '01-03 we can say that this is common then ( Oded co-auther of the article and the sole author of the book)