# What is a non-OWF?

Tags: security-definition, one-way-function

We know that  A function $f:\Bbb Z_2^n \longrightarrow\Bbb Z_2^m$ is a **(strong) one-way function (OWF)**, if:

- $f$ can be computed by a PT algorithm. Equivalently, there exists a PPT algorithm that on input $x$ outputs $f(x)$, for all $x\in \Bbb Z_2^n$.
- For all PPT adversaries $A$, there exists a negligible function $\operatorname{negl}_A(n)$ such that, for all large enough $n$, we have
  $$
  \operatorname{Pr}\left[f(x)=f(z): x \stackrel{\\\$}{\leftarrow}\Bbb Z_2^n,\ z \leftarrow A(f(x))\right] \leq \operatorname{negl}_A(n)
  .$$
  In other words, in terms of Games, for all PPT adversaries $A$ who play the Game $\operatorname{OWF}$ (getting $f(x)\in \Bbb Z_2^m$ and returning some pre-image $z\in \Bbb Z_2^n$), where

***Game $\operatorname{OWF}_f$***

- **Procedure** Initialize
- $x \stackrel{\\\$}{\leftarrow}\Bbb Z_2^n$
- Return $f(x)$
- **Procedure** Finilize($z$)
- Return ($f(x)=f(z)$)

there exists a negligible function $\operatorname{negl}_A(n)$ such that, for all large enough $n$, we have
$$\Pr[\operatorname{OWF}_f^A\implies \text{True}]\leq \operatorname{negl}_A(n). $$

***My Question here is how can we interpret formally the negation of this definition? So, what is a non-OWF $f$?***

My answer is that there exist an adversary $A$ such that the probability that $A$ wins the above Game is non-negligible (some people use the term *noticeable*).

Does this mean that the probability that, for any $x\in \Bbb Z_2^n$ (even if this $x$ is predefined by us), $A$ returns a correct pre-image $z$ of $f(x)$ is non-negligible?

In addition, does it mean that in this case we can feed $A$ with any $y\in \Bbb Z_2^m$, it can return us some $z\in \Bbb Z_2^n$ such that $y=f(z)$ with some noticeable probability? I think that this happens only if $f$ is surjective.

Thank you.

---

**Update.** So, to be even more precise, assume that we need to implement the following ***reduction***; We want to show that if a function $f$ is not an OWF, then we can factor any $N\in \Bbb Z^+$. Check Prop 3 of 2.4.2 of these [notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Egoyal/15356/lecture_notes.pdf). Then, we write a pseudocode to define an adversary $B$ against $N$, which invokes $A$. And it says that $A$ takes $N$ and returns some value.

I can understand that $A$ is an algorithm, so we can put in it any value. But, in $A(N)$, how do we precisely employ the fact that $f$ is not an OWF?

I would say that if $f$ is surjective, then $N=f(x)$ for some *specific* $x$. So, if $A$ succeeds means that it can find a valid pre-image $z$ of $f(x)$.

Is the event of picking a *specific* $x_0$ from $\Bbb Z_2^n$ and feed $A$ with $f(x_0)$ a subset of the event that we pick uniformly at random an $x$ from $\Bbb Z_2^n$ and feed $A$ with $f(x)$?

Comment: Nicely formatted question, but extreme nitpick: British English: "initialise" and "finalise", American English: "initialize" and "finalize" choose 1. "Finilize" seems a typo.

Comment: Yes, this is rare and requires encouragement. +1 for the nice format...

Comment: Thanks for the nice words, I try to be as clear as possible so that people are able to precisely understand my question and use the introduced notation as well.

Comment: Note that, once answered, do not change the question too much, this can make the answer invalid..

Comment: Sure, but I think all comes down to the non-onewayness of $f$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of a OWF involves a distribution over $x$. So the negation also involves a distribution.

"$f$ is not a OWF" means: [either $f$ is not polynomial-time, or]
there is a PPT adversary such that $\Pr[ \text{OWF}^{A}_f \Rightarrow \text{true} ]$ is nonnegligible function of the security parameter.

> My answer is that there exist an adversary $A$ such that the probability that $A$ wins the above Game is non-negligible (some people use the term noticeable).

I agree with this, but be careful: "non-negligible" and "noticeable" mean slightly different things. See [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/100186/192).

> Does this mean that the probability that, for any $x\in \Bbb Z_2^n$ (even if this $x$ is predefined by us), $A$ returns a correct pre-image $z$ of $f(x)$ is non-negligible?

> In addition, does it mean that in this case we can feed $A$ with any $y\in \Bbb Z_2^m$, it can return us some $z\in \Bbb Z_2^n$ such that $y=f(z)$ with some noticeable probability? I think that this happens only if $f$ is surjective.

The only thing we know about $A$ is that when you feed it inputs *exactly as distributed in the OWF game,* it has a certain property. This is a guarantee about $A$'s *probabilistic* behavior when receiving a particular *distribution* of inputs. We can't infer much about $A$'s behavior on any *particular* input. So I would *not* write "for any $x \in \{0,1\}^n$'' or "any $y \in \{0,1\}^m$,'' as you have done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Regarding noticeable term, indeed sometimes may mean different things, but in these notes https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~goyal/15356/lecture_notes.pdf I followed, he interprets it as a "significant" quantity.

Comment: Now, suppose that we want to implement a **reduction**, like in Prop 2 of 2.4.2  on the above notes; We assume that $f$ is not an OWF, and we want to prove that for any $N\in \Bbb Z^+$, we can break the *Factoring Assumption*. So, we try to build an adversary $B$ against $N$, and we used inside its pseudocode $A$. But we have to feed $A$ with $N$. So, how can we imagine happening this?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what it means to break the factoring assumption. See 2.4.1 of those notes. It doesn't mean "there is an algorithm that can successfully factor any $N$", it means "there is an algorithm that succeeds at factoring with non-negligible probability, when its input is drawn from a particular distribution." So the reduction algorithm receives its input $N$ according to some distribution, which conveniently happens to be the same distribution that the adversary sees in $\text{OWF}_f$.

Comment: Indeed, $B(N)$ plays the Game say $\operatorname{Factor}$, which picks to primes $p,q$ uniformly at random and returns their product $N:=pq$ to $B$ and his goal is to find these $p,q$. So, in our case, the Game $\operatorname{Factor}$ picks this $N=pq$ as we said and subsequently invokes $A$. Is the distribution of these $N$s the same as picking $x$ uniformly at random, consider it as a collection of $n^2$ $n$-bit integers,  pick the first two, and return $f(x)=pq=N$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I may open another topic :)